# Change the style color to custom color in Metro Framework?

Tags: c#, winforms, metroframework

I have implemented Metro Framework in my Windows Form Application. I want to change the style color to custom color. (As shown in the screenshot) How do I do this?
[image: Sample page]

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but it might help others looking for answers in the future.

If you are using the [nuget Metro Framework package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MetroModernUI/) for C# in Visual Studio then you need to set the "UseCustomBackColor" of the object to true:

```
metroTile_YourTile.UseCustomBackColor = true;
```

and then change the back color in the designer to "Custom" and pick the color, or set it programmatically:

```
metroTile_YourTile.UseCustomBackColor = Color.FromArgb(100,100,100);
```

This is true for a multitude of objects in the package, including buttons, dropdowns, etc. I hope that is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:** You can't.

A **workaround** would be to override the `OnPaint` method of the `MetroForm` and draw it yourself. For example:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
    base.OnPaint(e);

    // custom draw the top border
    using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.White))
    {
        int borderWidth = 5; // MetroFramework source code
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, 0, 0, Width, borderWidth);
    }
}
```

---

**Long answer**: I am using `MetroModernUI` from Nuget. And wanted to remove the top border.

Reading the source-code of the Framework, I found the method responsible for the draw of the top border, which is similar to the code above.

The method responsible for get the color for draw is `MetroPaint.GetStyleBrush(Style)`, where `Style` is the Enum `MetroColorStyle`. It is a switch-case:

```
public static SolidBrush GetStyleBrush(MetroColorStyle style)
{
    switch (style)
    {
        case MetroColorStyle.Black:
            return MetroBrushes.Black;
        case MetroColorStyle.White:
            return MetroBrushes.White;
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

Basically you are limited to choose one of the colors available. (or fork the code and live the freedom!)

Reference: [MetroModernUI (Github)](https://github.com/dennismagno/metroframework-modern-ui/blob/master/MetroFramework/Forms/MetroForm.cs)

Answer (score 2):

I realise this is an old question but this was driving me mad and I couldn't find answers anywhere. I did, however, figure it out so thought I'd share... As long as you don't mind editing the source code a little, there is a way to add custom colors.

**1. Start with the** `MetroColors` **Class**. Right at the bottom there is some code relating to a Custom option. Replace it with the following:

```
public static Color customColor = new Color();

public static Color Custom
{
    get
    {
        return customColor;
    }
}
```

**2. Next, move onto the** `MetroPaint` **Class**. Near the bottom, expand the `Helper Methods` region and add a case for Custom to `GetStyleColor`,

```
public static Color GetStyleColor(MetroColorStyle style)
{
    switch (style)
    {
        case MetroColorStyle.Custom:
            return MetroColors.Custom;
    }
```

`GetStyleBrush`and

```
public static SolidBrush GetStyleBrush(MetroColorStyle style)
{
    switch (style)
    {
        case MetroColorStyle.Custom:
            return MetroBrushes.Custom;
    }
```

`GetStylePen`. (Make sure to leave the defaults at the end)

```
public static Pen GetStylePen(MetroColorStyle style)
{
    switch (style)
    {
        case MetroColorStyle.Custom:
            return MetroPens.Custom;
    }
}
```

**3. Make sure that** the `MetroPens`

```
public static Pen Custom
{
    get
    {
        return GetSavePen("Custom", MetroColors.Yellow);
    }
}
```

and `MetroBrushes`have the Custom options at the end of them (I don't remember if they were already there or not)

```
public static SolidBrush Custom
{
    get
    {
        return GetSaveBrush("Custom", MetroColors.Custom);
    }
}
```

**4. Save your changes and build it**, then replace the `MetroFramwork.dll` in your project with the newly edited one.

**5. I'll assume you already have a** `comboBox` **hooked up to the** `StyleManager`. Add "Custom" to the end of the `comboBox` items (its index should be 15 as long as you haven't excluded any of the other colors) and add a `colorDialog` to the form.

**6. Add a** `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler to the `comboBox` and then add the following:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 15)
    {
        Color c = new Color();

        if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            c = colorDialog1.Color;
        }

        MetroColors.customColor = c;
        metroStyleManager1.Style = MetroColorStyle.Custom;
    }
    else
    {
        metroStyleManager1.Style = (MetroFramework.MetroColorStyle)Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedIndex);
    }
    Refresh();
}
```

Now when you select Custom from the `combBox`, the `colorDialog` will appear and you can choose any color you want. If you just wanted to change to a fixed custom color that you don't want to be changed, you can just specify the RGB and apply it on `FormLoad` instead:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MetroColors.customColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);
    metroStyleManager1.Style = MetroColorStyle.Custom;
}
```

You can repeat these steps as many times as you want to add new colors (Custom1, Custom2 etc.). Just remember to add these to the list in the `MetroColorStyle.cs` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
this.Style={color};
```

Comment: This has the same list if I select from its property window. Any other option to add custom color?

Comment: try Color.FromArgb(255, 232, 232)

Comment: This gives an argument exception **Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Color' to 'MetroFramework.MetroColorStyle'**

Comment: have your tried the syntax of Mariusz Adamczewski with that of mine: Color.FromArgb(255, 232, 232)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
this.Style = MetroFramework.MetroColorStyle.<color>;
```

Possible colors:

- Default
- Black
- White
- Silver
- Blue
- Green
- Lime
- Teal
- Orange
- Brown
- Pink
- Magenta
- Purple
- Red
- Yellow

So for example:

```
this.Style = MetroFramework.MetroColorStyle.Red;
```

You can use this on any MetroFramework control:

```
metroProgressBar1.Style = MetroFramework.MetroColorStyle.Blue;
```

You can also switch between light and dark theme:

```
this.Theme = MetroFramework.MetroThemeStyle.Light;
//or
this.Theme = MetroFramework.MetroThemeStyle.Dark;
```

Answer (score 0):

As already stated before, a custom color is not possible. However, you can use the already defined colors. (See @SomeCoder's answer)

If you want to make a ComboBox to change the theme/style you don't have to make a big switch statement with all the themes/styles, you can simply do this:

```
private void ColorComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Enum.TryParse(colorComboBox.Text, out MetroColorStyle color);

        this.Style = color;
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        this.Style = MetroColorStyle.Default;
    }

    Refresh();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this will work, but try to use

```
this.BackColor = (your colour)
```

Also please let me know if this is working or not.

Comment: Any other suggestions?